# How have two stores using the same two views

Tags: php, magento

I have a Mangento website that have two languages : **french** and **english**.

These two languages are registered in two different views associated with a store "MyCanadianStore"

So :

```
MyCanadianStore
    > French
    > English
```

But I need to add another currency (so all my products will have another price in Euro) for Europe customers so I thought about creating another store "Europe Store" that would be change according to the ip adress (I've already have done this part)

The problem is, my products and pages are already created for my **French** and **English** view and I don't want to re-create 5000 products and 150 pages for the **Europe > French** and **Europe > English**

So, is there a way of linking a view to multiple stores ?

If not, do you see another solution to my problem ?

Comment: hi please refer this: 
http://docs.nexcess.net/article/multiple-storefronts-with-magento.html

Comment: This link is only telling how to create a website > store > view but I already know that, I want to create a website, with 2 stores and each of them will use them same views.